# python escape dollar sign

Tags: python, mongodb

I am struggling to understand what's wrong with this syntax:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client.monitor
#cursor = db.monitoring_logs.find({"widget": "56dfed49a2988d9019000585;"})
cursor = db.monitoring_logs.find({"widget": {$in:["56dfed49a2988d9019000585;","56d58f5b1dc95f54460002f6;"]}})
print (cursor.count())
```

error message:

```
C:\Users\Nir.Regev\Anaconda3\python.exe C:/Users/Nir.Regev/PycharmProjects/anomaly/get_mongo_data.py
  File "C:/Users/Nir.Regev/PycharmProjects/anomaly/get_mongo_data.py", line 6
    cursor = db.monitoring_logs.find({"widget": {$in:["56dfed49a2988d9019000585;","56d58f5b1dc95f54460002f6;"]}})
                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1
```

is it the dollar sign ($) and if so how do get around this  ?

Comment: Try using `"$in"` instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to put quotes around any of the special strings in Python ('$in' in this case) - you might be looking at the Mongo docs which are written using javascript, not the pymongo client docs, which are written for Python clients (I have done the same ;) ).

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client.monitor
#cursor = db.monitoring_logs.find({"widget": "56dfed49a2988d9019000585;"})
cursor = db.monitoring_logs.find({"widget": {'$in': ["56dfed49a2988d9019000585;","56d58f5b1dc95f54460002f6;"]}})
print (cursor.count())
```